# Limiting Maximum Number of Search Results

Tags: php

I have the php file linked to xml file with a number of links. My aim is to limit the maximum number of search results to show up up-on typing in the search box. For example to have only 8 or 10 results. I don't know where to start. How can I go about this?.

php file

```html
<?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("links.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q)>0) {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++) {
    $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
    if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1) {
      //find a link matching the search text
      if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)) {
        if ($hint=="") {
          $hint="<a href='" .
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
          "' target='_blank'>" .
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        } else {
          $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" .
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
          "' target='_blank'>" .
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint was found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint=="") {
  $response="no suggestion";
} else {
  $response=$hint;
}

//output the response
echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: Add a counter variable. Increment the value for each link you read from the xml file. When you've reached 8 (or 10) links, stop reading results from the file.

Comment: Thank you @Phaelax z. Do you mean editing this php code above? or should I add those counter variable to xml?.  Please, would you show me?. I am new to this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of the issue is that you want to limit the amount of `hints` returned from the search. You aren't attempting to stop the search but rather to just restrict the output?

The changes which I've made is to turn `$hint` into an array, then at the bottom of the code it will use `array_slice` to start at the first position and return `$amountToShow`. Adding the element to `$hint` is done with `sprintf` that's purely for readability sake.

```
<?php

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("links.xml");

$x = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');

//get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_GET["q"];
$hint = [];

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q) > 0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < ($x->length); $i++) {
        $y = $x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
        $z = $x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
        if ($y->item(0)->nodeType == 1) {
            //find a link matching the search text
            if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue, $q)) {
                $hint[] = sprintf(
                    "<a href='%s' target='_blank'>%s</a>",
                    $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,
                    $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint was found
// or to the correct values
$amountToShow = 10;
if (count($hint) == 0) {
    echo "no suggestion";
} else {
    echo implode("", array_slice($hint, 0, $amountToShow));
}
```

Comment: Many thanks to you @hppycoder, simple and clear. It has solved. Be blessed.